# Could not download/find iOS 17.1.2 Simulator with Xcode 15.0/15.1

Tags: xcode15

Could not download/find iOS 17.1.2 Simulator with Xcode 15.0/15.1 having only 17.0 and 17.2

Referred below url
https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
This is the blocker for me to verify issue in specific version. iPhone 13 Pro Max with iOS 17.1.2
Can any one please suggest here.